# how can I fix this program so it won't return 'unknown' for negative input (boiling_point)

Tags: python, dictionary, difference

Here's the given for the problem I'm trying to solve:

*python Write a function that given a mapping from material to boiling points, and a boiling point temperature, will return :

- the material corresponding to the boiling, if it is within 5% difference
- 'UNKNOWN' otherwise

Function signature should look like : boiling_material(boiling_map, boiling_point)

An example boiling_map : Given input :
' Butane' : _0.5,
'copper' : 1187,
'Gold' : 2660,
'Mercury' : 357,
'Methane' : _161.7,
'Nonane': 150.8,
'Silver' : 2197,
'water': 100}*

A sample run of the program with the above input:

Enter boiling point > 359
Closest material : Mercury

Enter boiling point > 2000
Closest material : Unknown

I attempted to solve it and it's returning the right output when the inputs are positive numbers but it's only returning 'unknown' when  the inputs are negative.
**Example:**
Enter boiling point > -0.475
Expected Closest material : Butane
actual output: Unknown

This is my current code.

```
    boiling_map=dict()
boiling_map['Butane']=-0.5
boiling_map['Copper']=1187
boiling_map['Gold']=2660
boiling_map['Mercury']=357
boiling_map['Methane']=-161.7
boiling_map['Nonane']=150.8
boiling_map['water']=100

def boiling_material(boiling_map,boiling_point):
    closest='unknown'
    for material in boiling_map:
        if abs(boiling_map[material]) >=abs(boiling_point-(boiling_point*5//100)) and abs(boiling_map[material]-boiling_point)<=abs(boiling_point+(boiling_point*5//100)) :
            closest=material
    return closest



print(boiling_material(boiling_map,359))
print(boiling_material(boiling_map,-0.475))
print(boiling_material(boiling_map,0))
```

Comment: Your calculations are assuming `boiling_point` is positive.  If the material boiling point is `0`, and `boiling_point` is -0.475, then this calculation: `abs(boiling_point-(boiling_point*5//100))` returns `0.45125`, not `-0.45125`.  `0` will never be higher.

Comment: You could actually fix this by converting all your temperatures to Kelvin.  That would however modify the size of the 5% window dramatically for some of these materials.

Comment: @Tibrogargan removing the abs() will not solve the problem. Should I change the whole equation and think of another way to check if the temperature is within 5% difference?

Comment: @Tibrogargan oh I didn't think of converting! I'll try this out now

Comment: @Tibrogargan this fixed the butane problem indeed. However if the boiling point is 0 the course instructor is saying it should return unknown. Now it's returning butane (-0.5) too.

Comment: You didn't provide full details about the problem here - it makes a huge difference depending on what temperature scale you're talking about, and you didn't provide one.  `0° F` is `255.37° K` and `-17.78° C`.  5% of those is `0`, `12.77` and `0.86`.  Also, when you're talking about higher boiling points the window is massive.  So large in fact that for some materials 5% lower than the boiling point could also be below the melting point (for Metaldehyde that's easy).  The phrase "5% difference" is incredibly imprecise in this context.

Comment: Frankly, I would solve this problem using all three temperature scales just to illustrate the issue with the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.  The below is using Python 3.10.4, anything under 3.10 won't support using the `match` keyword.  Note that for some test temperatures you get known results on some temperature scales, but not on others.  Note that the results here are either "unknown" or a list of candidates.
Added a material and some test temperatures to make things interesting.

```
from enum import Enum
import sys;

class TemperatureScale(Enum):
    CELCIUS = 1
    KELVIN = 2
    FAHRENHEIT = 3

# boiling points are in kelvin
materials = { "Butane": 272.65
            , "Copper": 1460.15
            , "Gold": 2933.15
            , "Mercury": 630.15
            , "Methane": 111.45
            , "Nonane": 423.95
            , "Water": 373.15
            , "Propyl Alcohol": 370.65
            }

def kelvin_to_scale(temp, scale):
    match scale:
        case TemperatureScale.KELVIN:
            return temp
        case TemperatureScale.CELCIUS:
            return temp - 273.15
        case TemperatureScale.FAHRENHEIT:
            return 1.8 * (temp - 273.15) + 32
        case _:
            raise Exception('unknown scale')

def scale_to_kelvin(temp, scale):
    match scale:
        case TemperatureScale.KELVIN:
            return temp
        case TemperatureScale.CELCIUS:
            return temp + 273.15
        case TemperatureScale.FAHRENHEIT:
            return (temp*5//9)+459.67
        case _:
            raise Exception('unknown scale')

def test_material(boiling_point, scale = TemperatureScale.KELVIN):
    print(f'Test temperature: {boiling_point} {scale}')
    candidates = []
    for material in materials:
        bp = kelvin_to_scale(materials[material], scale)
        margin = abs(boiling_point)*5//100
        print(f'Testing {material} using {bp} +/- {margin}:\t{bp - margin} <= {boiling_point} < {bp + margin}')
        if (bp - margin <= boiling_point) and (bp + margin > boiling_point):
            candidates += [ material ]
    return candidates

# test values are in celcius
test_values = [ 2801, 359, -0.475, 0, 95 ]

for test_value in test_values:
    kelvin_value = scale_to_kelvin(test_value, TemperatureScale.CELCIUS)
    for scale in [ TemperatureScale.CELCIUS, TemperatureScale.KELVIN, TemperatureScale.FAHRENHEIT ]:
        print(test_material(kelvin_to_scale(kelvin_value, scale), scale) or 'unknown')
```